# from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas gives module not found error

Tags: python-3.7, reportlab

when trying to use `from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas` it gives the module not found error while if i `import reportlab` it does not give any errors.

I tried reinstalling reportlab.
installing reportlab with pip3 also did not work.

Comment: Which version of reportlab are you using `pip list` ?